# Sample space in the experiment of taking out balls, until green shows up.

Tags: probability

Let's assume that we have n black balls, and 1 more green.

We take out the balls from the bag, without replacement, until we get the green ball.

Let X be the r.v. representing the number of balls taken from the bag. $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$X=i <=>$ we've taken i balls, and i-th was the green one.

What is the sample space in this setting?

I ask this, because when someone asked me what was the probability of $X=i$, I said $$P(X=i)=P(B_1,...,B_{i-1},G_i)$$
$$=P(G_i|B_1,...,B_{i-1})P(B_1,...,B_{i-1})=\frac{1}{n+1-(i-1)}\frac{C^n_{i-1}}{C^{n+1}_{i-1}}=1/(n+1).$$ Then, they said if I'm counting correctly the possible cases in the denominator of $P(B_1,...,B_{i-1})$, since, for them, the sample space would be the set $\{(B), (B,G), (B,B,G), \cdots\}$, and $C^{n+1}_{i-1}$ seems to assume that events like $(B,G,B,...,B)$ may happen.

So, here's what I want to know:

1. What is the sample space $\Omega$?
2. Am I counting correctly in the denominator of the probability?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  The probability that $X=i$ is $\frac 1{n+1}$, since the Green one is equally likely to appear in any slot and there are $n+1$ slots. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Should specify:  I assume that you are drawing without replacement, though you didn't say that.  Of course the answer is different if you are replacing the balls each time.

Comment: @lulu I've edited my post, to make it more explicit.

Comment: Again, assuming that you are drawing without replacement, I'd have said that the sample space was just $\{1,\cdots, n+1\}$.  As to what the denominator should be, well that depends on how you do the calculation.  I'd have said it was just $n+1$, myself.

Comment: Should add:  I don't know what the $B_j$ refer to.

Comment: It may be worth stressing:  there is no unique notion of "sample space" in these problems.  You are modeling the underlying problem and there may be many ways to do that.  For instance, if you are tossing a pair of dice, it would be natural to regard the sample space as the set of ordered pairs of outcomes, or as the set of unordered pairs.  Both are perfectly valid, though one or the other might be better suited to any particular question someone might have in mind.

Comment: @lulu in one comment I think you're mixing $\Omega$ and $X(\Omega)$. Also, $B_j$ means that a black ball was take out at the j-th draw.

Comment: I don't know what $\Omega$ and $X(\Omega)$ are.  I would have said that the sample space was $\{1,\cdots, n+1\}$ because the answer has got to be one of those integers. Of course, you can describe it in different ways if you prefer.

Comment: To be clear:  with $n=3$, I see no meaningful difference between writing the outcome $(B,G)$ as $(B, G, B, B)$ or as simply the number $2$.  All three descriptions clearly refer to the same outcome.

Comment: @lulu how would you find $P(B_1, ..., B_{i-1})=\frac{\# favourable}{\#possible}$?

Comment: That's just the probability that $G$ is in a slot $≥i-1$.  There are $n+1-(i-1)=n-i+2$ such slots out a possible $n+1$ so $\frac {n-i+2}{n+1}$.

Comment: @lulu the way you solve it is from a very instinctive manner, at least to me... I'm interested more in a deduction using either combinations, or from first principles.